# search in post_excerpt with WP_Query wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Is posible to search in column post_excerpt using WP_Query?

I'm trying to implement a search in Wordpress with Woocommerce and Bishop because Ajax Search of Bishop seeks only post with type "product". I installed SearchWP Live Ajax Search and this work very good, but equal to Ajax Search of Bishop does not seek in "Product Short Description" (post_excerpt in database).

I am new in wordpress and still do not know it's limitations, so if there is no way to search using post_excerpt will use $wpdb and a query SELECT..., etc.

Well, thanks! :)

Comment: well, thanks for response, but I believe that is not possible include this column "post_excerpt" in the $args in the WP_Query

Answer (score -1):

I did not find how to search in post_excerpt column directly using `WP_Query`, but I found this tutorial that tells how to modify the where the query http://jamescollings.co.uk/blog/extending-woocommerce-search-query-include-custom-fields/

happy coding! :)

Comment: Not really helpful when you link a page (currently offline) instead of explaining the solution here.